# How to write a pandas table into an Excel table?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I have code:

```
def transpon(array):
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(array)
    index = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df)
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(df.unstack()).transpose()

    return new_df

array = {1: {2016: 22818888925.021294, 2017: 23215791927.55883, 2018: 24241415053.75489, 2019: 25526831987.89783, 2007: 18183059018.027966, 2008: 16868527277.51174, 2009: 18331809529.53519, 2010: 19724006864.797657, 2011: 20392912788.825798, 2012: 19580849153.840134, 2013: 22084393933.539394, 2014: 22030084567.47173, 2015: 21700822555.267574}, 2: {2016: 15081873888.10038, 2017: 15377071873.462284, 2018: 16253879799.12362, 2019: 16517025291.019705, 2007: 10038529774.615318, 2008: 11611749842.042978, 2009: 12040185617.510305, 2010: 12508816879.258118, 2011: 13711111085.100977, 2012: 13219008951.675236, 2013: 14209627046.021126, 2014: 15371996764.61913, 2015: 14417938720.997215}, 6: {2016: 0.6609381349660216, 2017: 0.6623539667069717, 2018: 0.6705004539991144, 2019: 0.6470456380505956, 2007: 0.5520814602571774, 2008: 0.6883677306864346, 2009: 0.6567919876164886, 2010: 0.6341924825418297, 2011: 0.6723468700662476, 2012: 0.6750988605150847, 2013: 0.6434239077958611, 2014: 0.6977729348945159, 2015: 0.6643959547744175}}

new_array = transpon(array)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("dataframe.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
new_array.to_excel(writer,sheet_name = 'Worktest', index=False)
writer.save()
```

But I am getting error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/TestWork/connect_bd.py", line 53, in <module>
    new_array.to_excel(writer,sheet_name = 'Worktest', index=False)
  File "C:\Users\shaa1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2127, in to_excel
    engine=engine)
  File "C:\Users\shaa1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py", line 662, in write
    freeze_panes=freeze_panes)
  File "C:\Users\shaa1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 1970, in write_cells
    for cell in cells:
  File "C:\Users\shaa1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py", line 627, in get_formatted_cells
    self._format_body()):
  File "C:\Users\shaa1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py", line 409, in _format_header_mi
    raise NotImplementedError("Writing to Excel with MultiIndex"
NotImplementedError: Writing to Excel with MultiIndex columns and no index ('index'=False) is not yet implemented.
```

And if you do not specify the `index = false`, it writes crookedly

[image: Incorrect write in Excel]

I need a write like this

[image: Correct write in Excel]

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52497554/blank-line-below-headers-created-when-using-multiindex-and-to-excel-in-python

Answer (score 0):

But why do not you just save the pandas dataframe in csv? You can do it with the `to_csv` function, https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html. Then, you can open it with Excel, LibreOffice. You can do the graphs and the calculations and save the file in the Excel/LibreOffice format. Also the code is simpler.