# MultiIndex DataFrame to Excel export problems

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

After exporting MultiIndex DataFrame to an Excel file, an additional row between the header and the rows is created. How can I avoid that?
[image]

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(out_xlsx, engine='xlsxwriter')
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='All Instances', merge_cells=True)
```

Did anyone experience similar behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a known issue/feature in Pandas. See this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/27772) for an explanation.

This Stack Overflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71305025/10238) is probably the best workaround I’ve seen.